# Disable user from saving .aspx content from browser by using "saving as" option

Tags: vb.net, browser

I have a .net website.
I need to disable the save as option from browser so that the user cant save some of the website pages in order to protect their content.I did disable right click.But user can select save as from browser's menu.
Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to lock down a website by disabling the save button. What is to stop a user just copying the text and pasting to another document. Right clicking an image and saving. Then there are differences between browsers etc. If you need to protect you information you may need to look at creating and displaying PDFs but this is also not an easy thing especially if the site is dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is impossible. If the user is able to read the information on his/her screen, there is always an option to copy the content.

How would you stop the user from taking a picture from his/her screen with a digital camera for example?